# Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: angularjs, git

I with a friend were working on a git branch other than master, named `userSummary`. This morning my friend merged the branch with master after making some changes but didn't delete the `userSummary` branch. I changed my branch from `userSummary` to `master` and did a pull on the `master`. 
Now my web app is showing some root scope error. And it's behaving in a weird way. The error is

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…2%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%22%5C%222016-10-13T09%3A31%3A36.003Z%5C%22%22%7D%5D%5D
```

I have been struggling on it since a long time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

As seen in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig):

This error occurs when the application's model becomes unstable and each `$digest` cycle triggers a state change and subsequent `$digest` cycle. Angular detects this situation and prevents an infinite loop from causing the browser to become unresponsive.

For example, the situation can occur by setting up a watch on a path and subsequently updating the same path when the value changes.

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function() {
  $scope.foo = $scope.foo + 1;
});
```

One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called. For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in getUsers()">{{ user.name }}</div>

...

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];
};
```

Since `getUsers()` returns a new array, Angular determines that the model is different on each $digest cycle, resulting in the error. The solution is to return the same array object if the elements have not changed:

```
var users = [ { name: 'Hank' }, { name: 'Francisco' } ];

$scope.getUsers = function() {
  return users;
};
```

The maximum number of allowed iterations of the `$digest` cycle is controlled via TTL setting which can be configured via [$rootScopeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider).

Comment: The docs couldn't solve my problem that's why I came here. I am sorry but its not helping.